# Pick a 3D Node in JavaFX from screen coordinates

Tags: 3d, javafx, coordinates, javafx-3d

Is there a way to pick a 3D node on the JFX scene with screen coordinates ?

Knowing that I am not using the Mouse, but use a Custom Touch Handler (Not the JFX Touch events).

What I've tried:

1. Emulate a MouseEvent from the Touch Handler and fire the event. The PickResult got from the event is always null.
2. Use the common way: Ray/Node collision by calling the (deprecated) method:  `Node.impl_pickNode(pickray, result)`, so I tried to get the PickRay:

   1. By calling: `Camera.computePickRay(double x, double y, PickRay pickRay)`, but the method is not public...
   2. Build it, but I need to convert the screen coordinates in 3D coordinates, but don't know how to do it with the JFX API.

Thanks for any input !

Comment: Are you Picking from Node to Node? Node to Camera? Camera to Node? All the above?
Currently there is no public picking api, I have followed a few conversations on Jira about them making it public.

Answer (score 1):

Jose Pereda recently contributed a RayCasting example to the free open source F(X)yz library:

https://github.com/FXyz/FXyzLib/blob/master/src/org/fxyz/tests/RayTest.java

It is still in flux but it might give you everything you need. This is similar to this question where he and @jdub1581 try to explain [javafx-8-3d-scene-intersection-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381119/javafx-8-3d-scene-intersection-point)