# Intersect TriangleMesh from screen coordinates in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

I have a TriangleMesh in javafx and a 2D point in screen space and i want to check whether any triangles in the mesh intersect with that point(basically same as clicking a point in the mesh except that i already have a predefined screen coordinate)

Note that i don't care where the intersection happened etc but only the fact whether it intersected or not.

I did try googling this and found some useful answers, especially one by José Pereda here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27612786/14999427

However the links are down

Edit: i did find a working link to it, however it just hardcodes the origin/target and im not sure how to compute these from the 2d screen point

Another idea i had was to copy the implementation from openjfx but after some research i figured that i'd have to copy a lot of internals and even then i wasn't sure if i would get it working so i scrapped that idea.

Goal: i want to use my mouse to create a rectangle at an arbitrary position in the mesh and then find all triangles that are inside that rectangle (i believe it's usually called rectangle selection in 3d modeling software)

Update: converting each triangle to 2d screen coordinates using Node#localToScreen and then doing a 2D point inside triangle test works perfectly however it also selects faces that are culled.

Update 2: after also doing the culling myself it works quite well (it's not perfect but it's mostly accurate)
Current code:

```java
Point2D v1Screen = view.localToScreen(mesh.getPoints().get(0), mesh.getPoints()
        .get(1), mesh.getPoints().get(2));
Point2D v2Screen = view.localToScreen(mesh.getPoints().get(3), mesh.getPoints()
        .get(4), mesh.getPoints().get(5));
Point2D v3Screen = view.localToScreen(mesh.getPoints().get(6), mesh.getPoints()
        .get(7), mesh.getPoints().get(8));
Point2D point = new Point2D(mouseX, mouseY);
boolean inTriangle = pointInTriangle(point, v1Screen, v2Screen, v3Screen);
// Back-face culling
double dxAB = v1Screen.getX() - v2Screen.getX();
double dyAB = v1Screen.getY() - v2Screen.getY();
double dxCB = v3Screen.getX() - v2Screen.getX();
double dyCB = v3Screen.getY() - v2Screen.getY();
boolean culled = ((dxAB * dyCB) - (dyAB * dxCB)) <= 0;
if (inTriangle && !culled) {
    view.setMaterial(new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE));
    System.out.println("Intersected");
}
```

Comment: Anything you can use in the `PickResult`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72322484/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72313844/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59329700/230513)?

Comment: unfortunately not, seems like i'll have to do all the math myself to construct the ray & intersect with each triangle, the former is which what im mainly struggling with currently (how to construct a ray from a point in screen space)

Comment: For others interested the original StackOverflow post about Ray Intersections refers to Github repo code that has been since moved to here:
https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz

Answer (score -3):

I think the answer to this question may help you. [How to correctly obtain screen coordinates of 3D shape after rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790379/how-to-correctly-obtain-screen-coordinates-of-3d-shape-after-rotation) If you can compute the screen coordinates of a 3D shape (triangle) the hit test should then be simple.

Comment: I did check this out and tested it but it seems like it's half broken even with 0 modifications to the code (the picking isn't pixel perfect) and when i tried it with a single triangle it was off by a lot. (btw i didn't downvote this answer)